# Subtype/supertype for teacher, student and admin as users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

Every entity whether it is teacher, student admin or superadmin, they have login credentials and a role.

So I have  decided to implement subtype and supertype relation.

```
Users
------------
id
email
password
roleId

Teachers
-------------
userId -> foreign key as well as primary key
name

Students
--------------
userId
name

School
-------------
userId
name
```

But school, teacher and students are also related to each other.
So teacher or student will have another foreign key `school_id`.

Should I go with this schema or drop the primary key constraint for userId in student, teacher and school.

Should I give them their own unique primary keys.

Comment: If I was going with this approach, I would store all data common to both teachers and students in the user table. I don't really see how a school can be a user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I agree. But `Studets` table will have two foreign keys `userId` which is also primary key and another `schoold` which will be nothing but again `userId`. I am having problem here.

Comment: @philipxy Sorry, but no that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

For example (schematically):

```
CREATE TABLE users ( id PRIMARY KEY,
                     name,
                     email,
                     password,
                     role_id FOREIGN KEY roles(id),
                     school_id FOREIGN KEY schools(id),
                     type ENUM('Teacher', 'Student'),
                     teacher_id FOREIGN KEY users(id), -- NULL for teachers
                     CHECK (CASE WHEN type = 'Teacher'
                                 THEN teacher_id IS NULL
                                 ELSE teacher_id IS NOT NULL
                                 END)
                   );
```

Tables Teachers and Students not needed.